# Is the product of a constant and a stopping time also a stopping time?

Tags: stopping-times, filtrations

If $\tau$ is a stopping time wrt $\mathcal{F}=\{\mathcal{F}_t : t \geq 0\}$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, then is $\alpha \tau$ also a stopping time?

I know that if $\alpha \geq 1$, then $\mathcal{F_{t / \alpha}} \subseteq \mathcal{F_{t}}$ and it follows that
$$\alpha \tau \text{ is a stopping time wrt } \mathcal{F}$$
and if $\alpha < 1$, then
$$\alpha \tau \text{ is a stopping time wrt } \{\mathcal{F_{t / \alpha}}\}$$
**Question:** Is $\alpha \tau$ a stopping time wrt $\mathcal{F}$ for any $\alpha$?

Comment: What do you think of the following investment scheme. Invest a lot of money in some stocks now. If the price crashes $\tau$ days from now, then sell the stock $\tau/2$ days from now. Can I do this? Do you see the connection between this and your question for $\alpha=1/2$?

Comment: No, I don't see the connection. How do I know that the price crashes $\tau$ from now? (how can I predict the future?)

Comment: You're right about inability to predict the future, and that observation is essentially the answer to your question.

Comment: I still don't get it... What if $\alpha \geq 1$? Wouldn't your example still make no sense although I know that $\alpha \tau$ is indeed a stopping time?

Comment: The analog of my example with $\alpha>1$ would ask about the scheme "If the price crashes $\tau$ days from now, then sell the stock $2\tau$ days from now." Admittedly it's not a very smart strategy, but it is something that you could do without predicting the future. The cases $\alpha<1$, $\alpha=1$, and $\alpha>1$ correspond to "predicting" the future, the present, and the past, respectively.

Comment: So the answer to "Is $\alpha \tau$ a stopping time wrt $\mathcal{F}$ for any $\alpha$?" would be "not necessarily".